# How to use decorator in react-native-chart-kit?

Tags: react-native

I'm discovering react-native-chart-kit and I found that in LineChart, we can use a function named: decorator but I didn't found any example ;

[image]

The link of documentation

If someOne has already experience on this  can help me

```
  componentDidMount() {
   this.GetData();
   }
  GetData = () => {
      const self = this;
      return fetch('http://192.168.1.3:80/graph.php')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        const dataClone = {...self.state.data}
        const values = responseJson.map(value => value.ChiffreAffaire);
        const label = responseJson.map(value => value.M500_NOM);
      dataClone.datasets[0].data = values;
      dataClone.labels= label;
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          data: dataClone,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
<LineChart
            data={this.state.data}
            width={Dimensions.get("window").width*0.99}
            height={400}
            yAxisInterval={1}
            chartConfig={chartConfig}
            bezier
            spacing={0.8}
            spacingInner={0.8}
            verticalLabelRotation={90}
            withInnerLines={true}
            //renderDotContent={({x, y, index}) => <Text>{}</Text>}
            style={{
              marginVertical: 20,
              marginLeft:2,
              marginRight:2,
              borderRadius: 16,
              borderWidth: 0.5,
              borderColor: 'grey'
            }}
            />
```

And this is what shown in my mobile screen (So as you see my x labels are not presenting correctely ) Any Idea??????

[image: the result in my scrren]

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-react-native-charts-with-dynamic-tooltips-64aefc550c95/

Comment: @keikai please check the code ,I edited  my post !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this nice tutorial:

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/adding-tooltip-to-react-native-charts-67606c5d3182

You should basically get the point data (setting a callback to onDataPointClick property from LineChart component) and transfer the point coordinates and value to the tooltip, a SVG component.